# How can I make the changing content align with the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the content that will change appear on the right side of my navigation bar align with with it but also make sure the navigation bar on the left remains static? Here is my code for my home page and my CSS files:

```css
html {
  color: #333;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Garamond;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #CCCCCC;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
  background#ccc;
}

#top_info {
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  border: 1px soild #c7c7c7;
  margin: 30px;
  color: #E00000;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #000000;
}


/*This makes the color Black appear for the available menu options */

a:hover {
  background: black;
  color: #E00000;
}


/*This makes the color red appear when the user hovers over the available menu options */

#navbar {
  height: 20px;
  clear: both;
}


/*This makes the navigation bar*/

#navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}


/*This makes the navigation bar list*/

#navbar ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  clear: both;
}


/*This makes the navigation bar options*/

#right_content {
  float: right;
  width: 390px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Manga</title>

</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mangastyles.css" />

  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="Manga-logo.png" width="250" height="200" alt="J-Manga" </div>

      <div id="top_info">Manga: Japanese Comic Books</div>

      <div id="navbar"></div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Manga.html">[ Home ]</a></li>
        <li><a href="Form.html">[ Form ]</a></li>
        <li><a href="Pictures.html">[ Pictures ]</a></li>
        <li><a href="Audio.html">[ Audio ]</a></li>
        <li><a href="Video.html">[ Video ]</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="right_content">
        <p> Manga are comics created in Japan or by creators in the Japanese language, conforming to a style developed in Japan in the late 19th century. They have a long and complex pre-history in earlier Japanese art.</p>
        <p> In Japan, as in other parts of the world, people of all ages read manga. The medium includes works in a broad range of genres some of which include: comedy, business, historical drama, adventure, science fiction and fantasy, and many others.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Anyone attempting to answer your question would need to turn it into a [mcve] either here, on [so], using the snippet button (`<>`) or on an external snippet website (jsFiddle, codepen, etc...). Delivering the snippet yourself, in the question a) shows respect for the other member's time, b) you make sure you linked all required resources so the snippet reproduces your issue and c) you greatly increase the chances of getting a proper answer. For example, in the above example, the contents of `Mangastyles.css` is unknown and (most probably) your issue depends on it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand. I don't really know what a snippet is exactly.  Is my code too long? I was at best just hoping for a small generic example of how to align text next to a navigation bar.

Comment: Mangastyles.css is known its the css file I put below my homepage code.

Comment: It's good to know the contents of the linked stylesheet is actually what you've shown in the question. A snippet is turning disparate pieces of code into a live, working example. There's a button labeled `<>` on the bar of code samples which opens an overlay with 4 panels: 1 for `html`, one for `javascript` and one for `css`. This will create a snippet that works and can be inspected, either inline or in full screen mode. I'll create it for you this time, but keep in mind, for future questions, it greatly improves your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: oh okay, thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, I can't anymore, as someone else did it. Unfortunately, they lacked the required rep to edit directly and their proposed edits now require approval from other 3 members. I approved it but it still needs 2 more votes. If I would have edited it, it would have simply applied. It's how [so] works. But I'm sure it will get approved soon. Meanwhile, I made an [`external snippet`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/97ws4twz/) using your code. I believe it's still lacking resources. Could you update it?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu you could have selected the **Improve Edit** option instead of waiting for other approval votes. That's what I did, and all I _"improved"_ was removing a return.

Comment: @hungerstar Thank you for that trick. I'll try it next time. :)

Comment: What other kinds of resources do you need? do you need snippets of my other web pages? Or like images I used because that's pretty much all that missing in the snippet for my home page code.

Comment: The question I have regards what you are expecting your header to look like. Are you expecting everything you have listed to line up on one line?

As it is, you are using a few block level elements that may make this more difficult without further styling. However, it is difficult to give you advice without knowing what you are seeing in your mind as the final product.

Comment: I was wanting to make the content appear on the right side of my navigation bar all on the same line, but its okay now I played around with the numbers in my css file and got my content to "appear" to be on the same line as my navigation bar. Sorry my question was so confusing :/